# React-table v6 reset page size to default value

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6

Is there any way to reset pageSize for `react-table-v6`? What I can do is only to change `defaultPageSize` value accessing ReactTable component state via refs but that will only set default value which still is the same but not reset user choice to default one.

Simple JavaScript like

```
 document.getElementById("pageSize").value = "10";
```

is not working on TableReact component.

Any tips on that?

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/usePagination.md) seem to suggest that you use `usePagination` and `setPageSize`

Comment: @LiorPollak that is for the v7. Also I'm using `PaginationComponent` in v6